# Different ways of int initiation

Tags: java

What is the difference between

```
int i = 5;
```

and

```
int i = 0b101;
```

I am trying to spot differences but failing to understand. Please help.

Comment: The second is a bit notation, ideal if you do bit operations. The generated compiled code is identical. (1*2² + 0*2' + 1*2° = 5)

Comment: First is a direct integer assignment and second one is a binary representation (a kind of binary lietral). The later was added in Java 7.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Comment: `int i = 0x5` will also be equivalent in the hex notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are different number bases for the same thing. They have the same effect, but in different cases, are more readable/recognizable as "magic" values.

In (unsigned) binary, 101<sub>2</sub> is 4<sub>10</sub>+1<sub>10</sub>, or 5<sub>10</sub>. Thus, `0b101` is a numeric literal that is the same as `5`.

You could write the number 10<sub>10</sub> as:

```
int tenAsDecimal = 10;
int tenAsHex = 0xa;
int tenAsOctal = 012;
int tenAsBinary = 0b1010;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand whatever you have said. But whta would be the advantage of doing something like this is beyond me?

Comment: More on [NumberSystems](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_fundamentals/computer_number_system.htm)

Comment: @LPD If you need to work with a number whose numerical properties are based around it in binary (e.g. if you're writing radio software that detects a pattern of "101010101", you'll be better off using binary literals for the correlation as opposed to base-10 ones. Others reading your code will more readily recognize the pattern)

Comment: Thanks.. got it.. so its more of a novelty then.. am i right?

Comment: @LPD More of a convenience than a novelty - it *does* have its uses.